# Else if statement, por que no funciona (Number(!numeroUsuario)

Tags: javascript, if, else

Simple pregunta, porque en esta seccion => **Number(!numeroUsuario)** NO invalida el 0 y me dice:

- 'Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido'

Se que si le paso el 0 al prompt me devuelve una string pero para eso he hecho **Number**(!numeroUsuario), ahora ya es numero. Si **numeroUsuario** ya me rechaza nativamente '0', ' ', null, undefined, false, y yo lo he negado **!numeroUsuario** deberia darme true y entrar en el bloque ya que tambien lo converti a numero con **Number**

Se que 0 es par, pero arriba antes le dije que convierta 0 string a 0 numerico y se que nativamente un 0 numerico lo rechaza, PERO deberia entrar ya que use **!**

No entiendo esto

```js
let numeroUsuario, modulo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  numeroUsuario = prompt('Introduce un numero');
  
  if (numeroUsuario === null) {
    alert('Por favor, introduce algún valor.');
  } else if(Number(!numeroUsuario) || isNaN(numeroUsuario) || numeroUsuario === '') {  
    alert('Por favor, introduce un valor numérico válido.');
  } else {
    if (numeroUsuario % 2 === 0) {
      modulo = 'par';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    } else {
      modulo = 'impar';
      alert('El numero ' + numeroUsuario + ' es ' + modulo);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas,

Creo que te has confundido al poner el contrario "!". Tienes que ponerlo antes de la función que te devuelve un boolean "Number()" para que entre.

Voy a explicarlo un poco más.
La función te está devolviendo un número, en este caso un 0. El 0 se evalúa a false, y a true si es mayor a 0, por lo que si lo que quieres es que sea true, tienes que usar el operador lógico de negación, que invierte el valor. Si tienes true lo pasa a false y viceversa.
Como tú lo que quieres es que entre (que sea true), tienes que invertir lo que te devuelva Number.

Quedaría así:

```
else if(!Number(numeroUsuario) || isNaN(numeroUsuario) || numeroUsuario === '')
```

Un saludo

Comment: Hola Alejandro, la verdad es que quiero que tenga esta estructura, si cancelo por un lado, si es cero, NaN o ' ' por otro lado y por ultimo si es un numero. La verdad no lo veo ahora mismo seguro que para ti toma un segundo podrias editar mi codigo por favor? Siempre manteniendo esa estructura, por un lado null y en la misma linea las 3 que te dije.
Seria de agradecer =) gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, a ver si ahora te resulta más facil entenderlo

Comment: Inclusive solo sería necesario usar: `else if (!Number(numeroUsuario))`

Comment: Ah ahaha la verdad nunca habia usado !Number(numeroUsuario) con el ! delante, solo pense que funcionaria de la otra manera ya que convierto a numero lo invertido con !, vamos que lo hago true igualmente (!numeroUsuario)

Comment: Si te ha servido la respuesta, espero que la valores como correcta :)

Comment: como solo usar el (!Number(numeroUsuario)
tambien quiero isNaN etc. Si me ha valido pero nose lo veo un poco confuso , osea lo entiendo pero creia que de la otra manera tambien entraria ya que convierto a numero lo invertido igualmente. Ya le dia al tic =)

Comment: Es que tienes que tener en cuenta que invertir 0 te sigue dando 0, por eso no funcionaba. Es como si no lo invirtieras. Al hacer la comprobación 0 es false, por lo que que no entraba en esa condición.

Comment: me refiero a que invierto 0 en plan=> nativamente cero numerico es false, por eso uso number, ahora ya es numero 0,  0 numerico DEBERIA ser true gracias a (!numeroUsuario)... Creo que me estoy liando un monton donde no debria pero bueno =(

Comment: Creo que no es lo mismo porque que 0 sea false y lo niegues no lo convierte en 1. El operador lo que hace es invertir el valor lógico, pero no el valor real. De todas maneras, no soy un experto, y quizás esto sería mejor preguntarlo aparte.